# How to use RedisTimeSeries module in Azure Cache for Redis?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-redis-cache, azure-caching, redistimeseries

I would like to use RedisTimeSeries module (latest feature) in Redis from .net core client in Azure.

1. I created Azure Cache for Redis (from RedisLabs) (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/) standard resource in the Azure portal.
2. Downloaded the .net redis samples code from https://github.com/rustd/RedisSamples.
3. When I compiled samples code, it downloaded the nuget package called StackExchange.Redis (among other libraries).
4. Played with samples to understand how redis works from .net client.
5. It appears that raw REDIS commands where wrapped by StackExchange.Redis library.

Next, I wanted to play with RedisTimeSeries (as described at https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/RedisTimeSeries).

The StackExchange.Redis .net library does not seem to provide any API to invoke RedisTimeSeries module related commands such as TS.CREATE, TS.ADD etc.

Here are my questions:

1. Is RedisTimeSeries module supported in Azure Cache for Redis (from RedisLabs)?
2. If supported, how do I invoke TS related commands from my .net core client?
3. If not supported, is there any other .net library that lets me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is RedisTimeSeries module supported in Azure Cache for Redis (from RedisLabs)?

Azure Cache for Redis, is not from RedisLabs but from MS, the only Redis vendor who currently supports Modules deployments is RedisLabs Cloud Pro (see: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/deployments/ and https://redislabs.com/partner/microsoft/)

> 2. If supported, how do I invoke TS related commands from my .net core client?

`DbSync.Execute("MyCommand", args)`

Answer (score 2):

It is coming soon on Azure Redis, see [redis enterprise features on azure cache for redis coming soon](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/redis-enterprise-features-on-azure-cache-for-redis-coming-soon/)

Enterprise tier will support RedisTimeSeries

[image]

Answer (score 1):

RedisTimeSeries has been GA in Azure Cache for Redis, Enterprise Tier, since March 2021.

[NRedisTimeSeries](https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/NRedisTimeSeries) the recommended .Net client for RedisTimeSeries